# Ajax request. Which callback is executed first complete or success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I could spike this to find out, but I'm going to use SO. In my unit tests (qunit) I use the `asynchShould` (alias for asynchTest) test. Part of the assertion is to wait for the completion/success of the request. Like this:

```
asyncShould('talk to customer list server', 1, function() {
    stop(2000);
    var forCustomerList = newCustomerListRequest();

    forCustomerList.page = 'helpers/helper.php';
    forCustomerList.data += '&action=customerListServer&DB=11001';
    var originalSuccess = forCustomerList.success;

    forCustomerList.success = function(msg) {
        if (msg.flash !== undefined && msg.data !== undefined && msg.status !== undefined) {
            ok(true, 'json structure correct')
        }
        else {
            ok(false, 'json structure not correct');
        }
        originalSuccess(msg);
        start();
    };

    testController.getServerData(forCustomerList);
})
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**success**

From the jQuery site http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> **complete(XMLHttpRequest,
> textStatus)Function**
>
> A function to be
> called when the request finishes
> (after success and error callbacks are
> executed)...

Comment: I don't remember how many times I've read that page and didn't see it.

Answer (score 6):

"complete" fires after "success" or "failure"